# Adding newline in JSON object Typescript and Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I've the following data, I wanted the text to appear in new line. I tried `\n`. But new line is not working,

Do I need to do anything else ? Please help

Below is my code.

```
title = {"text": "Hello \n World"}
```

and in app.html

```
{{title}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of angular innerHtml binding. Replace \n with br

```
title = {"text": "Hello <br /> World"}
```

and in html page

```
<p [innerHtml]="title.text"></p>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<div style="white-space: pre-line">{{title}} </div>`

Answer (score 0):

in typescript

```
title = {"text": "Hello \n World"};
```

in html

```
<div style="white-space: pre-line">{{title.text}}</div>
```

**what pre-line does is :-** Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will wrap when necessary, and on **line breaks**